# ERROR: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Unable to build EntityManagerFactory

Tags: java, mysql, web-services

I am getting errors in my webservice project, I am using mysql along with jersey,here is my code and the stacktrace:

AccountResource.java:

```
package com.mycompany.mavenproject1;

import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.EntityTransaction;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;
import javax.persistence.TypedQuery;
import javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaBuilder;
import javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery;
import javax.persistence.criteria.Root;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.DELETE;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.PUT;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;


@Path("/Customers")
public class AccountResource {

    //===========================================
    //=         Attributes
    //===========================================

        private EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("test");
        private EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
        private EntityTransaction tx = em.getTransaction(); 



    //===========================================
    //=         Constructor
    //===========================================



    //===========================================
    //=         REST API methods
//    //===========================================
// 
    @GET
    @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
    public List<Customer> getCustomers() {
       return allEntries();
    }

     public List<Customer> allEntries() {
        CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<Customer> cq = cb.createQuery(Customer.class);
        Root<Customer> rootEntry = cq.from(Customer.class);
        CriteriaQuery<Customer> all = cq.select(rootEntry);
        TypedQuery<Customer> allQuery = em.createQuery(all);
        return allQuery.getResultList();
    }

    @GET
    @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
    @Path("{id}")
    public Customer getCustomer(@PathParam("id") int id) {
        Customer test = em.find(Customer.class, id);
        em.close();
        return test;
    }

        @GET
    @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
    @Path("/Account/{id}")
    public Account getAccount(@PathParam("id") int AccountId) {
        Account test = em.find(Account.class, AccountId);
        em.close();
        return test;
    }

    @POST
    @Path("/transactions")
    @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    public Account saver(Account p) {
        Account test = em.find(Account.class, p.getAccountId());
        if (test == null) {

            Transaction tran1 = new Transaction();
            tran1.setType("Debit");
            tran1.setDate("16-09-1990");
            tran1.setDescription("this is a test 1");
            tran1.setTbalance(400);
            tran1.setTransact(80);
            tran1.setCard("1111");

            em.persist(tran1);

            p.getTransactions().add(tran1);

            tx.begin();
            em.persist(p);
            tx.commit();
            em.close();
        }
        return p;
    }

    @PUT
    @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    @Path("/update/{id}/{amount}")
    public Customer UpdateAccount(
            @PathParam("id") int id,
            @PathParam("amount") double amount, Customer b) {
        Customer test = em.find(Customer.class, b.getId());
        if (test != null) {
             Account a1 = new Account();
            double balance = a1.getBalance();
            double bal = balance + amount;
            a1.setBalance(bal);
            tx.begin();
            em.remove(test);
            em.persist(a1);
            b.getAccount().add(a1);
            tx.commit();
            em.close();
        }

        return b;
    }


 @POST
 @Path("/save")
 @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
 @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
 public Customer save(Customer p) {
 Customer test = em.find(Customer.class, p.getId());
 if (test == null) {
 tx.begin();
 em.persist(p);
 tx.commit();
 em.close();
}
 return p; 
 }

    @POST
    @Path("/newAccount")
    @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    public Customer newAccount(Customer p) {
        Customer test = em.find(Customer.class, p.getId());
        if (test == null) {

            Account a1 = new Account();
            a1.setAccountNumber("4234324234");
            a1.setBalance(200);
            Account a2 = new Account();
            a2.setAccountNumber("5654675756");
            a2.setBalance(400);

            em.persist(a1);
            em.persist(a2);
            p.getAccount().add(a1);
            p.getAccount().add(a2);

            tx.begin();
            em.persist(p);
            tx.commit();
            em.close();
        }
        return p;   
    }




    @DELETE
    @Path("/{id}")
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    public void deleteItem(@PathParam("id") int id) {
        Customer test = em.find(Customer.class, id);
        if (test !=null) {
            tx.begin();
            em.remove(test);
            tx.commit();
            em.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Account.java:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package com.mycompany.mavenproject1;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import javax.persistence.Embedded;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;

@Entity
public class Account implements Serializable {

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO) 
    private int AccountId;
    private String AccountNumber;
    private double balance;
    private String sortcode;

    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    private Collection<Transaction> transactions = new ArrayList<Transaction>();

    public Collection<Transaction> getTransactions() {
        return transactions;
    }

    public void setTransactions(Collection<Transaction> transactions) {
        this.transactions = transactions;
    }





//
//    public Transaction getTransactions() {
//        return transactions;
//    }
//
//    public void setTransactions(Transaction transactions) {
//        this.transactions = transactions;
//    }
    public String getSortcode() {
        return sortcode;
    }

    public void setSortcode(String sortcode) {
        this.sortcode = sortcode;
    }
    public double getBalance() {
        return balance;
    }

    public void setBalance(double balance) {
        this.balance = balance;
    }

    public int getAccountId() {
        return AccountId;
    }

    public void setAccountId(int AccountId) {
        this.AccountId = AccountId;
    }

    public String getAccountNumber() {
        return AccountNumber;
    }

    public void setAccountNumber(String AccountNumber) {
        this.AccountNumber = AccountNumber;
    }





}
```

Customer.java:

```
package com.mycompany.mavenproject1;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@Entity
// @Table 
@XmlRootElement
public class Customer implements Serializable {

    @Id 
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO) 
    private int id;
    private String name;
    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    private Collection<Account> account = new ArrayList<Account>();

    public Collection<Account> getAccount() {
        return account;
    }

    public void setAccount(Collection<Account> account) {
        this.account = account;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

Transaction.java:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package com.mycompany.mavenproject1;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Embeddable;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import static javax.ws.rs.client.Entity.entity;



//@Embeddable // Tells hibernate that this class is embedded as part of another class

@Entity
public class Transaction implements Serializable {

   @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    private String type;
    private String date;
    private String description;
    private double tbalance;
    private double transact;
    private String card;

    public double getTransact() {
        return transact;
    }

    public void setTransact(double transact) {
        this.transact = transact;
    }

    public double getTbalance() {
        return tbalance;
    }

    public void setTbalance(double tbalance) {
        this.tbalance = tbalance;
    }



    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getCard() {
        return card;
    }

    public void setCard(String card) {
        this.card = card;
    }




    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }





}
```

Persistance.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence 
   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">

    <persistence-unit name="test" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">

        <class>com.mycompany.mavenproject1.Account</class>
        <class>com.mycompany.mavenproject1.Customer</class>
        <class>com.mycompany.mavenproject1.Transaction</class>

        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bank"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value=""/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.validation.mode" value="none"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
        </properties>

    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>BankExample</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>BankingSkeleton</name>

    <properties>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.4.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.4.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.21</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.2</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
        </dependency>



    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources/META-INF</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                            <silent>true</silent>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                    <version>7.0</version>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>9.2.4.v20141103</version>
                <configuration>
                    <httpConnector>
                        <host>127.0.0.1</host>
                    </httpConnector>
                    <scanIntervalSeconds>3</scanIntervalSeconds>
                    <webAppConfig>
                        <!-- defaultsDescriptor>src/test/resources/jetty-maven-plugin-webdefault.xml</defaultsDescriptor -->
                    </webAppConfig>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

StackTrace:

```
Building BankingSkeleton 1.0-SNAPSHOT
------------------------------------------------------------------------

>>> jetty-maven-plugin:9.2.4.v20141103:run (default-cli) @ BankExample >>>

--- maven-dependency-plugin:2.6:copy (default) @ BankExample ---

--- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources (default-resources) @ BankExample ---
[debug] execute contextualize
Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
Copying 0 resource

--- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ BankExample ---
Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date

--- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:testResources (default-testResources) @ BankExample ---
[debug] execute contextualize
Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
skip non existing resourceDirectory /Users/declanbarnes/Downloads/BankingSkeleton 2/src/test/resources

--- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ BankExample ---
Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date

<<< jetty-maven-plugin:9.2.4.v20141103:run (default-cli) @ BankExample <<<

--- jetty-maven-plugin:9.2.4.v20141103:run (default-cli) @ BankExample ---
2016-12-20 15:08:09.448:INFO::main: Logging initialized @4282ms
Configuring Jetty for project: BankingSkeleton
webAppSourceDirectory not set. Trying src/main/webapp
Reload Mechanic: automatic
Classes = /Users/declanbarnes/Downloads/BankingSkeleton 2/target/classes
Context path = /
Tmp directory = /Users/declanbarnes/Downloads/BankingSkeleton 2/target/tmp
Web defaults = org/eclipse/jetty/webapp/webdefault.xml
Web overrides =  none
web.xml file = file:/Users/declanbarnes/Downloads/BankingSkeleton%202/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml
Webapp directory = /Users/declanbarnes/Downloads/BankingSkeleton 2/src/main/webapp
2016-12-20 15:08:09.575:INFO:oejs.Server:main: jetty-9.2.4.v20141103
2016-12-20 15:08:40.428:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:main: Started o.e.j.m.p.JettyWebAppContext@9a7a808{/,file:/Users/declanbarnes/Downloads/BankingSkeleton%202/src/main/webapp/,AVAILABLE}{file:/Users/declanbarnes/Downloads/BankingSkeleton%202/src/main/webapp/}
2016-12-20 15:08:40.429:WARN:oejsh.RequestLogHandler:main: !RequestLog
2016-12-20 15:08:40.468:INFO:oejs.ServerConnector:main: Started ServerConnector@5fba7249{HTTP/1.1}{127.0.0.1:8080}
2016-12-20 15:08:40.469:INFO:oejs.Server:main: Started @35306ms
Started Jetty Server
Starting scanner at interval of 3 seconds.
Dec 20, 2016 3:08:56 PM org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler initialize
INFO: Initiating Jersey application, version Jersey: 2.7 2014-03-12 18:11:31...
Dec 20, 2016 3:08:57 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.1.Final}
Dec 20, 2016 3:08:57 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.1.4.Final}
Dec 20, 2016 3:08:57 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
Dec 20, 2016 3:08:57 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
Dec 20, 2016 3:08:57 PM org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
INFO: HHH000402: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
Dec 20, 2016 3:08:57 PM org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20
Dec 20, 2016 3:08:57 PM org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
INFO: HHH000006: Autocommit mode: true
Dec 20, 2016 3:08:57 PM org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
INFO: HHH000401: using driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] at URL [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bank]
Dec 20, 2016 3:08:57 PM org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
INFO: HHH000046: Connection properties: {user=root, autocommit=true, release_mode=auto}
Dec 20, 2016 3:08:58 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
Dec 20, 2016 3:08:58 PM org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionFactoryInitiator initiateService
INFO: HHH000268: Transaction strategy: org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransactionFactory
Dec 20, 2016 3:08:58 PM org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory <init>
INFO: HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
2016-12-20 15:08:58.518:WARN:oejs.ServletHandler:qtp1532800776-19: 
javax.servlet.ServletException: A MultiException has 2 exceptions.  They are:|1. javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: test] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory|2. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: create on com.mycompany.mavenproject1.AccountResource|
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:392)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:381)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:344)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:219)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:800)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:587)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1125)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1059)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:215)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:497)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:620)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:540)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Path to Files:
[Image of File Path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m3WfF.png)

Comment: Please can you provide full path to files next time.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. I have added an image of my file paths. Thanks.